# Fixing Discontinuous Stream Networks using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, watershed, geometric-network, stream

I am currently working on a project in ArcMap 10.6.1 involving urban sewershed delineation, however, I am stuck with a discontinuous stream network. I took a LiDAR DEM from NOAA and subjected it to standard archydro tools to create the stream network (direction, accumulation, then raster calculator to set the accumulation threshold) but am stuck on how to make the networks continuous. I have tried filling the DEM prior to this analysis with less desirable results.

My overall goal is to identify storm drainage inlets that can be used as pour points to create sewersheds for the neighborhood shown below.

How can I represent the stream networks?

[image]

Comment: Rule is simple: no fill == no connectivity.

Comment: @FelixIP Filling the DEM first produces large areas of constant elevation; ruining the resulting stream network. Is there a way to utilize the fill tool to make these networks continuous without making significant changes the rest of the raster?

Comment: Perhaps start with sinks identification. Make deepest point in each No Data. Repeat fill etc. Best approach though for ww network is to use existing pipes as stream network. This is how I do it anyway.

Comment: Try Utah State University's TauDEM software (free!). Upon installation you get an Arc toolbox with numerous hydro-related tools.  Bug-free, and the ocumentation is pretty good.